# Can I migrate an AMI to a different region using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami

I want to migrate an AMI from one region to another. Manually I would just copy the AMI using the AMI copy feature to a different region.

How do I do it using CloudFormation script ?

Comment: You cannot use cloudformation for that. Cloudformation is region specific. Use tools like https://www.packer.io/ to create and manage AMI across regions and accounts.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do in an easy way with CloudFormation, but you can use the [AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) for that.

Your template could include an AWS Lambda function that accepts an AMI ID, source region and target region as parameters, and copies the image from one to another. You would then call it form within your CloudFormation stack using a custom resource.